# GWT 2.2 Compile Error Project with Restlet 2.0

Tags: java, gwt, restlet, gwt2

The following error appears when compiling my project with Google Plugin for Eclipse:

```
Computing all possible rebind results for 'org.restlet.example.gae.serialization.client.ContactResourceProxy'
         Rebinding org.restlet.example.gae.serialization.client.ContactResourceProxy
            Checking rule <generate-with class='org.restlet.rebind.ClientProxyGenerator'/>
               Checking if all subconditions are true (<all>)
                  <when-assignable class='org.restlet.client.resource.ClientProxy'/>
                     Yes, the requested type was assignable
                  Yes: All subconditions were true
            Rule was a match and will be used
            Invoking generator org.restlet.rebind.ClientProxyGenerator
   [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/D:/workspace/ehelios/org.restlet.example.gae.serialization/src/org/restlet/example/gae/serialization/client/Serialization.java'
      [ERROR]  Internal compiler error
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.JClassType, but class was expected
    at org.restlet.rebind.ClientProxyGenerator.generate(ClientProxyGenerator.java:206)
    at com.google.gwt.core.ext.GeneratorExtWrapper.generate(GeneratorExtWrapper.java:48)
```

Answer (score 0):

GWT 2.2 is backwards-incompatible in a way that has broken many third-party libraries. In this case, it looks like you're using Restlet for GWT.

In these cases, your only immediate remedy is to check out the source of the library and do a build yourself. As this is often complicated or impractical, your next best bet is to wait for the third party to release a GWT-2.2-compatible build of their library.

Specifically in the case of Restlet, you should probably stick with GWT 2.1 until Restlet 2.1 M3 is released "[next week](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.restlet/13597)".

Answer (score 0):

Restlet 2.1 M3 has just been released including support for GWT 2.2. Thanks for your patience
http://blog.noelios.com/2011/03/31/restlet-framework-2-1-m3-and-2-0-6-released/